# Does the red riding hood card allow you to move forward and use the path tokens again?

Tags: little-red-riding-hood

The rules state that when you draw a riding hood card you leave the path tokens on the cards after you flip them over and move forward.  Does this mean you get to use the tokens again, say, if you were to decide to stop gathering right away?  The rules imply this but do not explicitly explain that this is the intention of the card (to grant the ability to reuse gathered path tokens).  I only ask because being able to do so kind of breaks the story (doesn't make sense you could gather the same path items twice, really, but as a game mechanic helps a good deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly say yes.  Besides the rules implying this, there is no other reason that I can see for them to explicitly tell you to leave the tokens on the cards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you stop the collect you can move again Red pawn.